# Compare specific content type with tags

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a content type called 'message' which has tags. The idea is that when viewing a message, the sidebar shows a block that lists titles of other messages who have the same tags as the one the user is currently viewing. I reckon this can be done with a view, though I have no idea how to work this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with a context filter.